# how to binding nested form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

everyone,
I have this reactive form:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      methodology: ["X"],
      name: ["Q1"],
      sections: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          code: ["S1"],
          label: ['LS1'],
          subSections: this.fb.array([ 
            this.fb.group({
              code: ["S1-1"],
              label: ['LS1-1'],
              questions: this.fb.array([
                this.fb.group({
                  code: ["Q1"],
                  label: ['LQ1'],
                  answer: this.fb.array([
                    {
                      code: ["A1"],
                      label: ['LA1'],
                    }
                  ]),
                })
              ])
            })
          ]),
        })
      ])
    });
  }
```

I want to binding the value with the Template
So I tried:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <div>
        <mat-label class="label">Metodoly:</mat-label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="methodology" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <mat-label class="label">Name:</mat-label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
    </div>

    <div formArrayName="sections" *ngFor="let field of getSections.controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]='i'>
            <div>
                <mat-label class="label">Code:</mat-label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="code" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <mat-label class="label">Label:</mat-label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="label" />
            </div>
            
            <div formArrayName="subSections" *ngFor="let k of field.get('subSections').controls; let y = index;">
                <div [formGroupName]='y'>
                    <div>
                        <mat-label class="label">Code:</mat-label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="code" />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <mat-label class="label">Label:</mat-label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="label" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Property 'sections' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.

I also tried creating functions:

```
 get getSections(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.form.get('sections');
  }

  get getSubSections(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.form.get('sections.subSections');
  }

 <div formArrayName="subSections" *ngFor="let k of getSubSections.controls; let y = index;">
        ....
    <div>
```

but I got the the error in the second function:

> ctx_r0.getSubSections is null

I also tried:

```
<div formArrayName="subSections" *ngFor="let k of field.get('subSections').controls; let y = index;">
    ....
<div>
```

but I get the error:

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

The code is here :
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1vuevr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: can you create a stackblitz link with your code for error debugging.

Comment: I tried. My first time doing stackblitz, is it acessable?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `getSubSections` to a function with receive an `i` variable.

```js
getSubSections(i: number): FormArray {
  return (this.getSections.controls[i] as FormGroup).get(
    'subSections'
  ) as FormArray;
}
```

And provide the index of iterate `FormGroup` from `sections` `FormArray` to the `getSubSections` function.

```
<div
  formArrayName="subSections"
  *ngFor="let k of getSubSections(i).controls; let y = index"
>
  <div [formGroupName]="y">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v7sols?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It's works! But I don't like to use function called direct in the template, beside that one that is a get.